# DevOps - How to use different artifcats on stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have multiple artifacts and multiple stages. Can I use for example artifact A on stage A, artifact B on stage B? My problem is when I run stage A I am triggering all the artifacts and I don't want that.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved like this[image]